# Image rectification using a photographic reference scale

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

I'm working in a mechanical laboratory for which we want to develop a photographic ruler that allows us to make nice images for our publications. The goal it to obtain images that are:

- top view projection of the plane
- objects further from the camera should not become smaller
- 90 degree angles should be 90 degrees
- width & height aspects should be in the correct ratio

**We envision the following approach**

1. Make an image where we place a specimen on top of the ruler.
2. Remove background.
3. Correct perspective / transform to the top projection

**Issue**
We rectify in photoshop/gimp however we would like to automate this process, for speed, consistency and accuracy reasons. To automate the process I've looked at various different existing rulers. At the moment the design is such that we have a circle with crosshair on the ruler. We want to use this target to compute the projection as is discussed at [smallpond](https://smallpond.ca/jim/scale/perspective.html). For this reason we would have to recognize the circle, which became an ellipse, and the crosshair combination to calculate:

- Major / minor axis  (done)
- Eclipse tilt  (done)
- Horizon tilt (not done yet)

I've written a script, see below, in which you have to select the ROI where the ellipse is positioned, in which OpenCV will try to fit an ellipse to the largest feature. (I can do better here by fitting an ellipse to all features and then selecting the ellipse with the best fit and know how to do that, but that would make the example much longer).

**Question**
The problem is twofold:

1. Can I automatically detect ellipses & the crosshair without having to define the ROI manually?
2. Is there a better way to determine and correct for the perspective? I read about [homomorphic projections](https://blog.ekbana.com/skew-correction-using-corner-detectors-and-homography-fda345e42e65) and assume that it is possible to correct for perspective using them. I could add a 4th target to allow for this to work with a rectangle. But

**Code**

```py
import cv2


def findEllipes(img):
    """
    Obtain the best fit ellipse of the  largest contour.

    Parameters
    ----------
    img : array_like
        Image of the area where the ellipse is the largest feature.

    Returns
    -------
    ellipse : ellipse
        OpenCV ellipse deffinition of the largest contour.

    """
    # Select region of interest
    roi = cv2.selectROI("window", img, showCrosshair=True, fromCenter=True)
    x, y, w, h = roi
    img_roi = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]

    # Prepare ellipse detection
    imgray = cv2.cvtColor(img_roi, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)  # make grayscale
    ret, blwt = cv2.threshold(imgray, 127, 255, 0)  # make binary

    # Contour detection
    cnt, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(blwt, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    # Largest contour is the contour of interest
    len_longest = 0
    longest = None
    for i in range(len(cnt)):
        if len(cnt[i]) > len_longest:
            longest = i
            len_longest = len(cnt[i])
    contour = cnt[longest]

    # Fit the ellipse around this contour.
    ((centx, centy), (width, height), angle) = cv2.fitEllipse(contour)
    ellipse = ((centx+x, centy+y), (width, height), angle)
    return ellipse


# Read file
img = cv2.imread('input.jpg')

# Setup window for interactions
cv2.namedWindow("window", cv2.WINDOW_GUI_EXPANDED)
cv2.resizeWindow('window', 1920, 1080)
cv2.imshow("window", img)

# Selecting Regions Of Interest in which the ellipses can be found.
good = False
color = (255, 0, 0)
while good is False:
    print("Please select a region with a circle")

    result = img.copy()
    ellipse = findEllipes(img)
    cv2.ellipse(result, ellipse, color, 10)
    cv2.imshow("window", result)
    cv2.waitKey(1)

    response = input("Press 'y' if the ellipse fits well: ")
    if response == 'y':
        good = True
        cv2.ellipse(img, ellipse, color, 10)


cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

**Appended:**

[The ruler design. (we can edit it if necessary)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMkmt.png) 
[Photo with removed background.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zp6eL.jpg) 
[Basic rectification by hand in GIMP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2kbl.jpg) 
[Ellipse detection with OpenCV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OyNFJ.jpg)

**P.S.** I'm aware that the approach only works for planar objects, but that is the intention anyway.

Comment: you could use combinations of computer-detectable markers like QR Codes or Aruco Markers with knoen sizes and positions as your reference/ruler.

Comment: That sounds like such a cheat, but using the existent code that recognizes QR codes sounds like a smart trick. I'll try that.